# Retrieve Http get and post requests on Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there any built in tool on azure portal to fetch number of Http get and post requests for Azure App Service(Web App) for last 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view the Error logging, failed request logging and web server logging you need to enable diagnostics on the web app. There you can configure where the logging should happen blob storage, file system or table storage. Then there are options to download and view logs.  In this case you need to filter the logs to see the get and post requests.

Another option is to enable application insights in your application. This can be done by adding the appinsights tracelistener nuget package and it will start generating logs once the application is running . Then these insights data can be viewed on the azure portal.

If you wish to run analytics on the logs, that is also possible by having an azure HDinsight cluster ( big data)  to run jobs on the logs and generate reports. There will additional cost involved for doing this operation obviously.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Analyses-Windows-Azure-web-0b27d413